# How to ajust Arabic 'aarab' characters?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arabic

I am facing a problem while showing Arab on arabic language.  I had checked many same problem given in here on stackoverflow but none of them of is working for me.

Now the problem is that it is not showing arabic correctly in xcode nor in simulator. I have even installed the font on my mac and added it in simulator correctly.
[image]

```
 label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:kArabicFont size:24.0f];
label.numberOfLines=2;
 // label.text=@"اَلْحَمْدُ لِلّٰهِ رَبِّ الْعٰلَمِيْنَۙ۰۰۱";
// label.text = @"السلام عليكم";
label.text = @"بِسْمِ اللّٰهِ الرَّحْمٰنِ الرَّحِيْمِ";
```

Comment: Where is the problem? the text is displayed properly in your screenshot

Comment: check the Arab in the simulator for word لِلّٰهِ. they are not properly placed

Comment: I do not really see any problems, it looks fine. You can try different font, if you do not like this one.